# Explain why the code gets compiled successfully?

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>

void main()
{
    int a=5;
    int *__restrict p1=&a,*__restrict p2=&a;
    printf("%d\n",*p2);
}
```

Why this code gets compiled in gcc without any error though a pointer qualified by restrict is the only means by which the object it points to can be accessed?

Comment: Looking at [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Restrict) >>The programmer, not the compiler, is responsible for ensuring that the pointers do not point to identical locations.>>  `restrict` means that the compiler assumes that `p1` and `p2` points to different location. But the compiler does not check this assumption : that is the job of the programmer.

Answer (score 2):

`restrict` is a hint to the compiler that no other pointer will access that memory. It does not mean that the compiler should check if there is another pointer, it means the opposite: the compiler doesn't really need to check this since you tell it there is none.

Answer (score 2):

Your program actually has undefined behavior.

Nothing in the standard (afaik) says that misusing `restrict` requires a diagnostic from the compiler, and section 6.7.3.1.4 of C99 standard only says that if you violate the restrict usage rule then the result is undefined behavior.

From section 6.7.3.1.11 they also give this code example:

```
{
    int * restrict p1;
    int * restrict q1;
    p1 = q1; // undefined behavior
    {
        int * restrict p2 = p1; // valid
        int * restrict q2 = q1; // valid
        p1 = q2; // undefined behavior
        p2 = q2; // undefined behavior
    }
}
```